# Koa & Passport Missing credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, koa, koa-passport

I have a Koa server that uses Passport to authenticate users against an Array,
and a React client. After successful login, the following requests are not authenticated as the cookie is undefined. The `authenticate` function's `error` parameter has:

```
{ message: 'Missing credentials' }
```

After browsing the site, I fixed the usual errors, calling the returned function of `authenticate`, adding `{credentials: 'include'}` to `fetch` etc, but still I have the same problem.

Middleware list:
`router.use(cookie.default());`

`app.use` :

koa-body, koa-session-store (also tried with koa-session), passport.initialize(), passport.session(), router.routes(), koa-static

local strategy

```
passport.use(new Strategy((username,password,callback)=>{
    var u =  users.find(u=>u.username == username);
    return (u  && password == 'password')?  callback(null, u ):callback('user not found', false);
}));
```

/login authenticate

```
.post('/login', (ctx)=>{
    console.log(ctx.request.body);
    return passport.authenticate('local',(err,user,info,status)=>{
        if(user) {
            ctx.login(user);
            ctx.body = {success: true}; // works correctly
            ctx.redirect('/login-success'); 
        } else {
            ctx.redirect('/login-failure');
        }
    })(ctx);
});
```

/login-success

```
router.get('/login-success',async(ctx)=> {
    return passport.authenticate('local',(err,user,info,status)=>{
        console.log(err); // "Missing credentials"
    })(ctx);
    await ctx.response;
    ctx.body = {success: true};
}).
```

Client call

```
let body = JSON.stringify({username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password});
let result = await fetch('http://localhost:4200/login',{method:'POST',credentials: 'include',body, headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is actually simple, but the reason is hard to find.

`async` middleware must either call `await next()` or `return next()` at the end.
Otherwise a 404 error is caused.

Adding `await next()` to the `async /login-success` callback, fixed the issue.

Documentation: https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-middleware-is-not-called